# Is there a way to query WSL environmental variables from within Windows / Command prompt?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On my quest to make my [WSL Windows Toolbar Launcher](https://github.com/cascadium/wsl-windows-toolbar-launcher) working, I found out that my attempt to set environmental variables for WSL from within command prompt futile:

Within command prompt, I can do a `wsl export DISPLAY=192.168.208.1:0.0`, but `wsl echo $DISPLAY` or `printenv DISPLAY` will return nothing.

Is querying or even setting WSL environmental variables even possible from within command prompt?

P.s. In my case, I have those set in my .bashrc but running a script via wsl seems to have done nothing to the variables, as the GUI does not forward to the X-server on Windows 10 (host).

Answer (score 1):

I only know of one environment variable that is passed between WSL and the
Command Prompt: `WSLENV`.

For `WSLENV` to be passed, one must invoke the other,
meaning that a WSL session invokes `cmd.exe`,
or that a `cmd.exe` session invokes `ubuntu` (or another distribution).

For more information, see the Microsoft article
[Share Environment Vars between WSL and Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/).